# If $p(x)$ has even degree and a positive leading coefficient and $p(x)\ge p''(x)$, then $p(x)\ge0$

Tags: polynomials, problem-solving

This is my solution, though not too sure of its rigor:

If $p(x)$ has $n$ degree,then we differentiate $n+1$ times, and and this polynomial will equal zero. We then integrate this $n+1$ times using $p(x)\ge p''(x)$, meaning that the integral of the integral is greater or equal to zero, and carry on integrating till we reach $p(x)$, which then must be greater or equal to zero.

AKA $p(x)>p''(x)\cdots>0$

Comment: What do we mean by inequality of two functions? Does it mean $\forall x(p(x) \ge p''(x))$?

Answer (score 2):

Hints in highlights:

First, be sure you understand why $\;\lim\limits_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)=+\infty\;$ .

Next: suppose there's $\;a\in\Bbb R\;$ s.t. $\;f(a)<0\;$ . By the above + continuity, differentiability of $\;f(x)\;$ it follows $\;f(x)\;$ has *a local minimum* at some point where the value of the function is negative.

Now use the given data and get a contradiction.

Comment: ah, so at the minimum the second derivative must be positive, contradicting p(x)>p''(x), as if p(x) is negative p''(x) is also negative. Damn thats so nice.

Comment: @grigori Yes...almost. At an extremum point the *first derivative* must vanish, but it could be that **also** the second one vanishes. The point here is that at that minimal point, say $\;x_0\;$, we're given $\;f(x_0)\ge f''(x_0)\implies f''(x_0)<0\;$ , which already says that point is a maximum.